A function called by multiple MPI processes which shows a message only once
I need a C function which is called by multiple MPI processes but shows a message using printf only once. The set of the processes which call the function is unknown until runtime. For example, assume the set of all processes is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}. One time the processes {0, 1, 2} call the function, another time the processes {1, 4}, etc. Everything related to the solution must be implemented as a single function.
I guess the solution can be like this: Inside the called function, a communicator can be created from the processes calling it. Then the process of rank 0 of this new communicator prints the message.
To be honest, I'm in a hurry and may not find time to try to implement my guess. As some of you may have a solution already, I posted the problem as a question. By the way, this is not a university or school exercise.

No need to create a communicator, simply pass the rank of the process that should print the message.

@GillesGouaillardet, When one of the processes calls the function, it doesn't know what other processes will also call it. Maybe because of this, creating a communicator is also impossible here. What I want is a special version of printf function, which every time that is called with the same arguments by a group of processes, produces just one output.

I'm coming to the conclusion that my problem is itself wrong.

The behavior you want to achieve is not possible with collective or P2P communication. With RMA, you can basically implement a shared-memory approach of your task by atomically updating a single memory location. You still need a preparation during initialization of the program and a cleanup at the end.
The following code prints the message exactly once, no matter how often printOnce is called:
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int winStorage = 0;
MPI_Win win;

void init() {
  MPI_Win_create(&winStorage, sizeof(winStorage), 1, MPI_INFO_NULL,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);
}

void fini() { MPI_Win_free(&win); }

void printOnce(int rank) {
  static int done = 0;
  if (done)
    return;

  int value = 1;
  int result = 0;
  MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, 0, 0, win);
  MPI_Get_accumulate(&value, 1, MPI_INT, &result, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, 1, MPI_INT,
                     MPI_SUM, win);
  MPI_Win_unlock(0, win);
  if(result==0)
    printf("Print exactly once at rank %i\n", rank);
  done = 1;
}

int main() {
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  init();

  if (rank % 2)
    printOnce(rank);

  fini();
  MPI_Finalize();
}


Thanks. I voted it up. I'll accept this answer once I've studied it more carefully.
